# expected an identifier and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, object

Hi,

I have this code:

```
obj = {"ignoredid":"3329"},{"ignoredid":"19693"};
hit = "3329";
if (Object.values(obj).indexOf(hit) > -1) {
   console.log('has it');
} else {console.log('doesnt');}
```

but I get a warning that says: `expected an identifier and instead saw an expression`

Why is that? This is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/o7u5L90h/1/

the code works fine on the fiddle despite the warning but not on my actual project (there it will always output "doesnt" no matter what) so I wonder if it will work once I get rid of the warning. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean to do with `obj = {ignoredid : 3329},{ignoredid : 19693}`? Are you trying to create an array of objects?

Comment: I guess you can say so. Imagine I have many users and that number is their ID.

Comment: The problem is the syntax, it's clearly not valid JS. You probably meant what Unmitigated suggested. `const arr = [{"ignoredid":"3329"},{"ignoredid":"19693"}];` You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if an array contains a value.  `if (arr.some(o => o. ignoredid === hit)`

Comment: you mean its not an object?

Comment: No, an object cannot have multiple properties with the same name and they would all be inside the same "{}". Maybe you were thinking `{ignoredid: 3329, ignoredid: 1963}` which would ignore the 3329.

Comment: is that a valid expression? They have the same identifier.

Comment: @CainNuke Did you try it? It's valid, but it doesn't behave as (I guess) you expect, as I mentioned in my comment, and explained in detail in my answer, it is syntactically valid but duplicate properties are ignored and the last one wins out.

Comment: I see, thank you for the elaborated explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want array of objects? Then you can do something like this

```js
// Helper function to check array of objects
const hasIt = (obj, val) => {
  for(const v of obj) if(v['ignoredid'] === val) return true;
  return false;
}

// Define array of objects
const obj = [{"ignoredid":"3329"},{"ignoredid":"19693"}];

// Test it
if(hasIt(obj, "3329")) console.log('has it');
else console.log('doesnt');
```

Or with more recent approach

```js
// Define array of objects
const obj = [{"ignoredid":"3329"},{"ignoredid":"19693"}];

// Test it
if(obj.find(o => o.ignoredid === '3329')) console.log('has it');
else console.log('doesnt');
```

Comment: You can/should use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) since you don't actually use the object that you're finding. Just to be semantically accurate. However, the question was about "expected an identifier and instead saw an expression" not how to check if an array item contains a value...

Comment: The recent approach works great, thank you!

Comment: @JuanMendes Sure, there is multiple working solutions as always

Comment: @tarkh That's not correct, at StackOverflow, we strive to ask questions that can be answered objectively. We don't ask people to solve full problems (which we agree could have multiple solutions). You did not really explain why his code didn't work and why it didn't throw a syntax error. So as much as the OP has code they can work with, they do not understand what they were doing wrong.

Comment: @JuanMendes well I thought that there is just a typo and OP forgot to put square brackets. Because otherwise, if the problem was really in objects key duplicate, his example should looks like this: `obj = {"ignoredid":"3329","ignoredid":"19693"};`. Anyway thanks for your time and quality approach)

Comment: @tarkh If the OP had only forgotten the square brackets, they wouldn't be calling `Object.values(obj)` They intended to create an object as you can tell by one of the their comments "you mean its not an object?"

Answer (score 1):

To answer your real question, what is happening there is that the statement `obj = {ignoredid : 3329},{ignoredid : 19693};` does not cause a syntax error but does not do what you expect it to do.

Though it's not clear what you expected to happen . That's why a lint is warning that `expected an identifier and instead saw an expression`

It's being interpreted as something close to the following:

```js
obj = {ignoredid : 3329}, {ignoredid : 19693};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Is interpreted as
obj = {ignoredid : 3329}
{ignoredid : 19693}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Or
((obj = {ignoredid : 3329}), {ignoredid : 19693});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

In both cases, the literal `{ignoredid : 19693}` is being discarded and not used by the program.

Note that if you started [writing code that was using `const/let`](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/8098856ea7f95cf66703f69b1a7b363a/ba6cb6d1de8d97a37dac83046a11b7013cff2178) or even var, you wouldn't have this problem and you'd be told you have a real syntax error and you wouldn't get this weird behavior. That is because a `VariableDeclaration` is not an `Expression`, and expressions separated by commas is what's happening here. See the end of the answer for further details.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment

```js
const obj = {ignoredid : 3329}, {ignoredid : 19693};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

### Explaining current behavior

If you intended it as `obj = {ignoredid : 3329, ignoredid : 19693};`, that would mean that the `obj` would be `{ignoredid : 19693}`, that is, the last property with the same name wins out.

This is why you were always getting `console.log('doesnt')`, your object did not contain a value of `3329` only `19693`;

### Solution

As suggested by [tark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829445/227299), Umitigate and me, you should use an array. I just wanted to answer the real question since the behavior is bit odd even outside of your quirky declaration

### Gorier Technical Details Explaining Error Message

If you analyze the [syntax tree of your example](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/7fac0fb38d26c93f063b8031d14d35b0/b97a303ba0d15a8edce18457067933ece49aa526), you'll notice that the body of the program is an `ExpressionStatement` but it does not contain an assignment directly, instead, it contains a nested `SequenceExpression` which contains a separate `AssignmentExpression` and an `ObjectExpression` which is not what you intended

However, if you analyze the syntax tree of [obj = {"ignoredid":"3329"};](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/64e4cb54f375c43c65b3fc36705d807c/b808128daf4d3fc2e23792143df2091e6b0997e4), you'll notice that there's an AssignmentExpression nested directly in the first `ExpressionStatement` of the program

So the message is indicating that it expected an `Assignment` but instead saw an `Expression`